# JCo (SAP) in OSGi (Karaf) JCO_ERROR_RESOURCE

Tags: java, apache-camel, osgi, apache-karaf, jco

I'm using JCo connector to write and read IDocs from a SAP System using Java.

In "Normal Java" this works without problems.

```
    server = JCoIDoc.getServer(SERVER); 
    server.setIDocHandlerFactory(new MyIDocHandlerFactory());
    server.setTIDHandler(new MyTidHandler());
    MyThrowableListener listener = new MyThrowableListener();
    server.addServerErrorListener(listener);
    server.addServerExceptionListener(listener);
    server.setConnectionCount(1);
    server.start();
```

Now... I want to bundle this code and put it in a OSGi Container (Karaf). But it crashes immediately in this line:

```
server = JCoIDoc.getServer(SERVER);
```

The error is:

> com.sap.conn.jco.JCoException: (106) JCO_ERROR_RESOURCE: Server SERVER
> does not exist
> at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.StandaloneServerFactory.update(StandaloneServerFactory.java:338)
> at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.StandaloneServerFactory.getServerInstance(StandaloneServerFactory.java:175)
> at com.sap.conn.idoc.jco.JCoIDoc.getServer(JCoIDoc.java:301)

I can't understand why is this happening... Do I need some kind of special configuration? Or is not possible run this on OSGi.

I know that I can use **camel-sap** to do the connection, but I want to try a non camel solution.

Comment: Are all the dependencies deployed to Karaf?

Comment: Yes. This is not a dependency issue (I think). I had to install the dependencies when I used camel-sap.

Comment: Have you packaged the JCo library and the IDOC adapter into separate bundles?

Comment: Yes... My camel routes using sap are working (kinda) ok....

Answer (score 1):

The SAP connector is not really supported in OSGi from the SAP side. So the default initialization might not work so well.

On the other hand I know that [hibersap](http://hibersap.org/example/) is working very well in OSGi. 
So you should be either able to figure out how they make the connect or simply use their abstraction in the first place. Their nice pojo bindings make SAP usage quite convenient.

I have used hibersap in Apache Karaf at a customer and it works very nicely since [version 1.2.0](http://hibersap.org/news/2015/03/13/hibersap-1-2-0-released/).

Comment: It seems that Hibersap does not support iDocs... bummer

Comment: "The SAP connector is not really supported in OSGi from the SAP side." - Interesting that it works perfectly inside ADT which is an Eclipse extension that in turn is running within an OSGi framework...

Comment: It works if you know how to do the initialization correctly but as far as I know SAP does not really support it. I would be happy about any pointer otherwise as our customer might need that support.

Comment: Btw, in general I would probably avoid hooking directly into SAP for extracting and creating idocs. I know of no integration platform from IBM IIB to others that do it in a safe manner. If SAP PI is available let that extract the idoc and delivery it to a queue or to a file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the error message

> com.sap.conn.jco.JCoException: (106) JCO_ERROR_RESOURCE: Server SERVER
>   does not exist

has anything to do with OSGi. It just says that the default JCo runtime cannot find and load the configuration for the JCoServer (which you named "SERVER").
In your working "normal Java" setup this must have been stored in the property file `SERVER.jcoServer`. In your OSGi environment this file is either missing, not stored in the right directory or the application is lacking the required read permissions on the file system. By default, JCo searches for those `<destinationName>.jcoDestination` and `<serverName>.jcoServer` configuration property files in the processes' current working directory.